# How to call deepcopy with super in python?

Tags: python, copy, super

I have 2 classes, let's call them Class1 and Class2(Class1), and Class2 derives from Class1.

In Class1, copy.deepcopy works very well and I **don't** want to implement a method **deepcopy** on Class1.

Now, I have an instance i2=Class2(someParameters). I want to make a deepcopy of i2 as in instance of Class1.

I cannot call copy.deepcopy(i2) because this would deepcopy i2 as in instance of class2 (with signature problems in my case).

I cannot call super().**deepcopy**(i2) because **deepcopy** is not found in class1, and one falls back to the computation of copy.deepcopy(i2) as an instance of class2, and we go to an infinite loop.

How to proceed then to call the builtin copy.deepcopy(i2), regarding i2 as an instance of Class1 ?

Thank you for your ideas, Laurent.

EDIT: As asked in the comments, an example of code to show the signature problem if I simply call copy.deepcopy

```
import copy
from copy import deepcopy


class Class1(object):
    pass

class Class2(Class1):
    def __new__(cls,start):
        eClass1=Class1.__new__(cls)
        Class1.__init__(eClass1)
        eClass1.start=start
        return eClass1

instanceClass2=Class2(1)
copy.deepcopy(instanceClass2)
```

The answer from the interpreter:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "essaiDebug7.py", line 18, in <module>
    copy.deepcopy(instanceClass2)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 329, in _reconstruct
    y = callable(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 93, in __newobj__
    return cls.__new__(cls, *args)
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of inheriting `Class1`, create a object of `Class2 in Class1`? Like:

```
class Class2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.class_1 = Class1()

# Then deepcopy
copy.deepcopy(class_2.class_1)
```

**Note**: It would be great if you can share the real scenario. Because, based on the problem you mentioned, I do not think that your classes are inheritable. If they are, *I do not understand why you just want to copy parent class?*

Comment: The parent class and the child class don't have the same signature, there are more parameters in the child class. Thus If i try to deepcopy the parent class using  copy.deepcopy, a recursive procedure is started. When this recursion is at the level of the parent, the Python interpreter complains like:  TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 1 arguments (2 given)

Comment: Moinuddin, you're right, it is more clear with an  example. Just added it.